# Using try catch even if no exception is expected

Tags: c#, exception

This is a public method which **I don't want it to throw exception in any case**.
In this example, I can't see a case where exception is thrown (am i missing something?), what is the BKM in this case? Is this a matter of preference? or there are guidelines in those cases.

```
    public IEnumerable<DataEnumerable.Column> GetCollectionSchema(string collectionName)
    {
        // Is this try catch block redundant?
        try
        {
            if (CoordinationDataCollection != null)
            {
                var collection = CoordinationDataCollection.FirstOrDefault(x => x.CollectionName == collectionName);

                if (collection != null)
                {
                    return collection.Schema;
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            _log.Error("Error occurred while trying to get collection schema", ex);
        }

        return new List<DataEnumerable.Column>();
    }
```

Comment: If something goes wrong, do you not want to be told about it?

Comment: What if CoordinationDataCollection is null?

Comment: @Arran - NO, i don't care.

Comment: If an item in CoordinationDataCollection is null, x.CollectionName will throw a null pointer exception.

Comment: Swallowing exceptions is just a bad idea, at least log them.

Comment: @Yosi the compiler might care...

Comment: I'd hate to have to debug this **if** something went wrong

Comment: @Liam - thanks, i added validation for CoordinationDataCollection.

Comment: Returning `null` is not very good idea. If caller forgets to check for null, then you'll get NullReferenceException. Return empty collection instead.

Comment: @lazyberezovsky I agree with you, but only for IEnumerable<T> not for e.g. List<T>, then the caller should check for null.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments :) Swallowing exceptions is the last thing i want to do i asked if there is a chance to get an exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't want it to throw exception in any case.

That's not possible. If the stack is nearly exhausted, it will throw a StackOverflowException which you cannot suppress.

> In this example, I can't see a case where exception is thrown (am i
>   missing something?)

The lambda expression that is passed to `FirstOrDefault` will throw if the collection contains null values.

Catching and logging all exception is sometimes the right thing. You might need to suppress a warning if you use code analysis.

Answer (score 2):

It is okay for public methods to throw exceptions in exceptional cases.  As long as these are documented then it should be fine.

In your example, if the `CoordinationDataCollection` is `null` then it would throw an exception.

Rather than suppressing any potential exceptions, it might be better to either document them, or allow them to be raised and allow the caller to decide what to do.

The above is just an example; a whole host of other things can go wrong.

Comment: @Yosi The updated code looks good. I do not think the try catch is redundant if you do not want any kind of errors being thrown.  You are also logging the error rather than just ignoring it; which is also good.

Answer (score 1):

What you have to think about in this case for instance is what happens if your DataCollection file changes in an update and the field `CollectionName` changes? Or what happens if the connection to the database is unavailable.

That's what you are checking for in your try catch when you simple code such as that, you know that your code won't fall over - the catch is to catch unexpected issues aka exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, public method must verify its input parameters:

```
Contract.Requires(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(collectionName));
```

The second thing: you should catch only those types of exceptions, that are prospective for your code. In other words, the method you've posted shouldn't catch `Exception`, because from the point of caller, it is not clear, why your method has returned an empty collection - either it is really empty, or exception happen.